# YDN: error with message InvalidStateError on Firefox ver 44

Tags: javascript, ydn-db

We have strange issue. Our application is using Ydn.js (JS code for using browser-internal database). On one Firefox, it works without error, but on the other Firefox, it gives error:

> Error: InvalidStateError: url: http://aaa.aa.aa/ydn.db-jquery.0.6.3.js, line:82 > column: 346

Both browsers had the same version (44.0).
Additionally after reinstallation of Ydn to newest version, still the same. One browser shows error, the other is working ok.

Is it possible that Firefox instance or database is broken?

Answer (score 0):

Such [bugs are common](https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db/issues/40) on Firefox pre-release build.